# Javascript Sorting array of objects works with explicit declaration, breaks when using variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, asynchronous

I'm working with an API that's returning JSON data, and I want to sort that data chronologically- by the releaseDate (an integer) property of the objects.

A sample of the data:

```
let all_albums = [
  {
    "releaseDate": 1461913200000,
    "critic_rating": 69,
    "user_rating": 57,
    "average_rating": 63
  },
  {
    "releaseDate": 1380006000000,
    "critic_rating": 79,
    "user_rating": 75,
    "average_rating": 77
  },
  {
    "releaseDate": 1321344000000,
    "critic_rating": 78,
    "user_rating": 79,
    "average_rating": 78.5
  },
]
```

If I copy/paste this into a separate file from my project I can sort it using:

```
 let sortedAlbums = all_albums.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.releaseDate - b.releaseDate;
});
```

However if I try to implement this into my project, I can iterate through the JSON the same way, print to console the same way, all the data is identical to what I demonstrated above -- but I am unable to sort this data set.

I come from a python background, so the world of asynchronicity is new to me. Is this related? Or, How do I sort objects that have just been called from an API?

----------------------------Edit----------------------------------

Thank you all for your comments so far. I've refactored some variables, cleaned up the code quite a bit per your recommendation. Still though, the issue persists when calling directly from the API. Here's the full code with example call, (albeit, with censored mashape key)

```
$(function () {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api-marcalencc-metacritic-v1.p.mashape.com/person/drake/album',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            "X-Mashape-Key": "----------------------------",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            handleDiscography(data);
        },
    })
});

const allAlbums = [];

function Album(releaseDate) {
    this.releaseDate = new Date(releaseDate).getTime();
}

function addAlbum(releaseDate) {
    const a = new Album(releaseDate);
    allAlbums.push(a);
}

function handleDiscography(data) {
    const album = data[0].CreditMediaPairItems;
    $.each(album, function (key, val) {
        const releaseDate = val.Item.ReleaseDate;
        addAlbum(releaseDate);
    });
    return data
}

const sortedAlbums = allAlbums.sort((a, b) => a.releaseDate - b.releaseDate);
console.log(sortedAlbums);
```

Comment: There's nothing asynchronous in this case. Once you have the data in your object, sorting is a sequential operation.

Comment: Agree with @Geuis. You can add the relevant code to the question so that it can help answering...

Comment: Try doing `a["releaseDate"] - b["releaseDate"]`

Comment: No @TimHan. That isn't needed. Accessing by property name is the correct way to do this.

Comment: You are probably sorting before the data is retrieved, I guess, as you mention asynchrony in the question, I would recommend you post something that demonstrates the problem, rather than showing something that works

Comment: @Geuis there is something to do here with asynchronous nature of javascript. The OP is dealing with a global variable inside async handler. That could create potential bug which could be hard to debug. That's the case here

Comment: I've added how to actually sort to the answer, hope it's useful once you sorted out the asynchronous problem in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is indeed an async problem.

The code in the `success` callback of the ajax request is executed after this code:

```
const sortedAlbums = allAlbums.sort((a, b) => a.releaseDate - b.releaseDate);
console.log(sortedAlbums);
```

[`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the array. So after the call of `sort` both `sortedAlbums` and `allAlbums` reference the same array.

Because no data is requested at that time, the `sort` is called on an empty array and nothing is sorted.

The next problem is that `console.log(sortedAlbums);` does not show the content of `sortedAlbums` at the time it has been logged, but of the time it has been first inspected in the developer tools. So at the time you look at it the request has finished, and the `allAlbums` which is now referencing the same object as `sortedAlbums` has been populated. But this happened after you sorted the empty array.

The simplest way would be to place the sort and log in the `success` callback:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api-marcalencc-metacritic-v1.p.mashape.com/person/drake/album',
  type: 'get',
  dataType: 'json',
  headers: {
    "X-Mashape-Key": "----------------------------",
    "Accept": "application/json"
  },
  success: function(data) {
    handleDiscography(data);
    allAlbums.sort((a, b) => a.releaseDate - b.releaseDate);
    console.log(allAlbums);
  }
})
```

A more cleanup solution would look something like this:

```
function Album(releaseDate) {
  this.releaseDate = new Date(releaseDate).getTime();
}


function handleDiscography(data) {
  const album = data[0].CreditMediaPairItems;
  return album.map(val => new Album(val.Item.ReleaseDate))
}

function getAlbumData() {
  return $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api-marcalencc-metacritic-v1.p.mashape.com/person/drake/album',
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      headers: {
        "X-Mashape-Key": "----------------------------",
        "Accept": "application/json"
      }
    })
    .then(data => handleDiscography)
}


getAlbumData()
  .then(allAlbums => {
    allAlbums.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.releaseDate - b.releaseDate;
    });

    console.log(allAlbums)
  })
```

In this example you completely got rid of the global object, which hould be always avoided, especially with async code.

Comment: Thank you so so so much. I knew it was something simple, but I'd have never gotten there without you.

There were a lot of great comments here, all caught the exact same issue. Although yours was the most concise answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

I've cleaned up your example code a little, but functionally its identical. It sorts fine.

```
const allAlbums = [
  {
    'releaseDate': 1461913200000,
    'critic_rating': 69,
    'user_rating': 57,
    'average_rating': 63
  },
  {
    'releaseDate': 1380006000000,
    'critic_rating': 79,
    'user_rating': 75,
    'average_rating': 77
  },
  {
    'releaseDate': 1321344000000,
    'critic_rating': 78,
    'user_rating': 79,
    'average_rating': 78.5
  },
];

const sortedAlbums = allAlbums.sort((a, b) => a.releaseDate - b.releaseDate);
console.log(sortedAlbums);
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "releaseDate": 1321344000000,
    "critic_rating": 78,
    "user_rating": 79,
    "average_rating": 78.5
  },
  {
    "releaseDate": 1380006000000,
    "critic_rating": 79,
    "user_rating": 75,
    "average_rating": 77
  },
  {
    "releaseDate": 1461913200000,
    "critic_rating": 69,
    "user_rating": 57,
    "average_rating": 63
  }
]
```

Here's some styling tips since you're a fellow Python programmer. While there isn't an official standard style guide, there are general recommendations.

Use single quotes. camelCase only. Double spaces, not tabs.

When dealing with arrays and object literals, you almost always want to use `const`. `let` and `var` are only needed if you are reassigning the same named variable to a different value. When working with arrays and objects, you are free to modify their properties since you aren't reassigning the variable.

When declaring functions, 90% of the time the fat arrow syntax will help to prevent bugs dealing with `this`. The other 10% of the time is when fat arrows cause the bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what your code should probably look like with some comments. Looks like you are trying to use a global variable `allAlbums` that is set in document ready event with asynchronous result.

But you're trying to use that variable outside of the document ready event handler so it's too early to access it as the data has not even been attempted to be loaded and even if it was the loading data is asynchronous so you can't set it with a value because the value is available in the future (or not at all if it fails).

You could only access `allAlbums` in document ready and set it to a promise value so you know when the actual value is available.

If allAlbums is shared with other code then don't just sort it as sort will mutate it and maybe when you use it somewhere else you don't expect it to be sorted a certain way. If you do want it sorted then please remove the `.map(x=>x)` before the `.sort`

```
//All albums is the result of asynchronous action so better store it
//  as a result of asynchronous action (promise)
var allAlbums = $.Deferred().resolve([]);
function Album(releaseDate) {
  this.releaseDate = new Date(releaseDate).getTime();
}
const logSorted = (message,albums) =>
  albums.then(
    albums => albums.map(x=>x).sort((a, b) => a.releaseDate - b.releaseDate)
  ).then(
    sortedAlbums=>console.log(message,sortedAlbums)
  );
$(function () {
  //set allAlbums to a promise
  allAlbums = $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api-marcalencc-metacritic-v1.p.mashape.com/person/drake/album',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
      "X-Mashape-Key": "----------------------------",
      "Accept": "application/json"
    }
  })
  .then(
    data =>
      data[0].CreditMediaPairItems.map(
        val =>
          new Album(val.Item.ReleaseDate)
      )
  );
  allAlbums.then(
    albums=>
      logSorted(
        "all albums is set with results so should log sorted:",
        albums
      )
  );
});

//it is kind of pointless to try and use all albums outside of he document ready
//  because document ready is an event that you don't know when it happens unless
//  code is inside document ready.
logSorted("all albums should be empty so sorted is empty too",allAlbums);
```

When you solved your asynchronous problem you still need to sort, here is an example of how to compose functions to build a multi column sort:

```js
const sorter = getter => comparer => (a,b) => 
  comparer(getter(a),getter(b));

const compareNumbers = (a,b)=>a-b;

const compareStrings = (a,b)=>a>b?1:(a<b)?-1:0;

const sortReleaseDate = sorter(x=>x.releaseDate)(compareNumbers);

const sortSomeStringValue = sorter(x=>x.someString)(compareStrings);

const sort = (sorters) => (a,b) => {
  const recur = (index) =>{
    if(index===sorters.length){
      return 0;
    }
    const [sorter,direction] = sorters[index];
    const result = sorter(a,b);
    if(result!==0){
      return result*direction;
    }
    return recur(index+1);
  }
  return recur(0);
};

//example on how to use:
const sampleArray = [
  {someString:"a",releaseDate:3},
  {someString:"a",releaseDate:2},
  {someString:"a",releaseDate:1},
  {someString:"b",releaseDate:3},
  {someString:"b",releaseDate:2},
  {someString:"b",releaseDate:1},
  {someString:"c",releaseDate:3},
  {someString:"c",releaseDate:2},
  {someString:"c",releaseDate:1}
];

console.log(
  "someString descending then releaseDate ascending",
  JSON.stringify(
    sampleArray
    .map(x=>x)//copy so we won't change original
    .sort(
      sort([
        [sortSomeStringValue,-1],//sort by by some string descending
        [sortReleaseDate,1]//sort by release date ascending
      ])
    ),
    undefined,
    2
  )
);

console.log(
  "releaseDate descending then some string ascending",
  JSON.stringify(
    sampleArray
    .map(x=>x)//copy so we won't change original
    .sort(
      sort([
        [sortReleaseDate,-1],//sort by release date descending
        [sortSomeStringValue,1]//sort by by some string ascending
      ])
    ),
    undefined,
    2
  )
)

console.log(
  "only releaseDate descending",
  JSON.stringify(
    sampleArray
    .map(x=>x)//copy so we won't change original
    .sort(
      sort([
        [sortReleaseDate,-1]//sort by release date descending
      ])
    ),
    undefined,
    2
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, your explanation is incredibly clear. I hadn't even gotten to mutli-column sort yet but that was going to be my next step! Very helpful, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The array data you provided, has releaseDate started with small 'r'. But you are using a ReleaseDate to access the property.If that's a typo , fix it.

Of course there is something to do with asynchronous nature of javascript. your ajax call is asynchronous. So the synchronous javascript finish executing before the success handler of asynchronous ajax  call kicks in. You must write all the async code inside success handler which deal with the returned data which comes from the server.What you should do is

You can not populate a global variable using async code.That means put the allAlbums variable inside success handler.Pass the data that you got from server to handleDiscography function. And write all the code that deals with the data inside the success handler.That means these codes will be executed when data will be retrieved from server

```
$(function () {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api-marcalencc-metacritic-v1.p.mashape.com/person/drake/album',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            "X-Mashape-Key": "----------------------------",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        },
        success: function (data) {
                    // these codes will kick in after success handler kicks in
                    var allAlbums = []
                    allAlbums = handleDiscography(data)
                    sortedAlbums(allAlbums)
                    console.log(data)
        },
    })
});
```

Modify the handleDiscography function :

```
function handleDiscography(data) {
    const allAlbums = [] // declare a local variable
    $.each(album, function (key, val) {
        const releaseDate = val.Item.ReleaseDate;
        addAlbum(releaseDate,allAlbums); // pass the allAlbums to addAlbum variable.array's are passed by reference,remember it !
    });
    return allAlbums // return the allAlbums local variable
}
```

add a second argument to catch the allAlbums variable passed from handleDiscography function

```
function addAlbum(releaseDate,allAlbums) {
    let a = new Album(releaseDate);
    allAlbums.push(a);
}
```

The way you wrote it will be executed immediately.So your code is executing way before the data being fetched from server.Global allAlbums variable is empty. So no sorting happens.So, declare sortedAlbums as a function so that you can call it later from success handler of ajax call

```
const sortedAlbums = (allAlbums) => {
    allAlbums.sort((a, b) => a.releaseDate - b.releaseDate)
};
```

Comment: How does the code know when to call sortedAlbums, it depends on a variable called allAlbums that is available at some point in the future and is being set in document ready. Yet code using allAlbums is outside document ready so don't even know if there is an attempt of it being set and assumes it's already set with an array of values even though the request may not be finished yet (document ready may not have been fired yet too). Maybe you should have a look at promises and figure out why this answer doesn't solve anything.

Comment: In case you didn't notice, I completely omitted the global allAlbums variable.It has been relocated inside success handler.success handler will be executed in a synchronous manner. You can see that the returned value of handleDiscoGraphy function is a array of release date object which is passed to allAlbums variable.SortedAlbums is called after that. So it will be executed synchronously.This code has already been tested using setTimeout mimicking the delay of remote call